# Bash script doesn't work on different Ubuntu versions

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I wrote a bash script to verify hard drive usage and send a notification if the usage hits a percentage of capacity:

```
#!/bin/bash

Name=$(hostname)
current_usage=$( df -h | grep '/dev/sda5' | awk {'print $5'} )
max_usage=65%

if [ ${current_usage%?} -ge ${max_usage%?} ]; then
    mailbody="Hard drive is running out of space at Virtual Machine ${Name}. Current usage: ${current_usage}."
    echo ${mailbody} | mail -s "Hard Drive Usage Alert" root
fi
```

The script works fine when run in a VM with Ubuntu 20.04

However, if run in Ubuntu 18.04 I get the following message:

```
/etc/cron.daily/df-check:
/etc/cron.daily/df-check: line 7: [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

Any idea on why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `/dev/sda5` is not the correct block device (making `${current_usage%?}` empty)?

Comment: Thanks steeldriver, you're totally right!. I knew it was a silly issue.

Comment: And quote your variables. And use `shellcheck` to de-lint your code.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. Case closed.